# How to add separate Portrait and Landscape splash Images to Android config.xml gap:splash

Tags: cordova, splash-screen, phonegap-build

The question here is how to allow for separate (landscape and portrait) splash images in PhoneGap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unable to find a satisfactory answer for a long time, I finally spent a few hours messing with it and was able to get it to work in the following way: define two items for each android size- on the portrait files, DON'T put width and height attributes, and on the landscape DO put them.

Here is my code so others can follow:

EDIT: THE CODE BELOW IS FOR PHONE GAP BUILD VERSIONS 2.7 THROUGH 3.0. FOR NEWER VERSIONS, SEE https://stackoverflow.com/a/24002601/700111 AND http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens.

THIS DID NOT WORK - when i had width and height on the portrait files:

```
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-n7-landscape.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" width="1280" height="800" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" width="1280" height="720" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" width="800" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" width="480" height="320" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" width="320" height="200" />
```

And this is the WORKING CODE

```
 <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi"/>
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-n7-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi"/>
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi"/>
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi"/>
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi"/>

<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-n7-landscape.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" width="1280" height="800" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" width="1280" height="720" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" width="800" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" width="480" height="320" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" width="320" height="200" />
```

I was able to have different landscape and portrait files using this code.

Hope this helps someone!

--techdude

Comment: Where did i should use this code? i am using Phonegap 3.0.0 Build. Please help me.

Comment: This code goes in the config.xml file. Note that this is for phonegap build, not phonegap api. The regular phonegap api has its own solutions that have been answered other places here. I am not sure if this will work with the latest version of phonegap, but I used it with 2.7.0.

Comment: @techdude I don't know why, but this did work for some reason. Have you had any luck with using 9-patch splash screens though?

Comment: Yeah, 9 patch works great if you are building specifically for android, I haven't gotten it to work on ios though. The main problem is that for this scenario I needed to be able to do a full screen photograph like splash. if you are just putting a logo in the middle of the screen then 9 patch should work for you. Glad to here that it worked, though. The splash screen capabilities should be better documented.

Comment: No luck until I added gap:qualifier to plugin. Check my new answer for this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685705/landscape-and-portrait-images-for-phonegap-build-splash-screen/24366772#24366772

Comment: @jeek, works great for 3.4. Thanks for sharing. As mentioned before in these comments, the code is for 2.7 so it is good to see that now there is a better, less gimmiky way to do it in the newest versions. Also the docs specify yet another way to do it for PGB 3.5.

Comment: @techdude: Yes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Phonegap 3.4.0, I had to add "gap:qualifier" to make it work:

```
<gap:splash gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" gap:qualifier="land-ldpi" />
<gap:splash gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" gap:qualifier="land-mdpi" />
<gap:splash gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-landscape" gap:qualifier="land-hdpi" />
<gap:splash gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" gap:qualifier="land-xhdpi" />
```

Comment: what about splash screen for portrait ?! Is it like  gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" ?

Comment: Looks like the latest version of PGB supports landscape and portrait splashes natively. Awesome! When I wrote this, it was a work around to get it working on what is now a very outdated version of PGB. Check out the new docs at http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens.

Comment: The original code only works on phone gap build 2.7 through about 3.0. I will update answer.