# Landscape and portrait images for phonegap BUILD splash screen?

Tags: javascript, xml, adobe, config, phonegap-build

I wondered if it was possible to have 2 seperate images in a  phonegap build app for the splash screen? One for potrait and one for landscape.

At the moment, when I open the app, it displays the splash screen and if i change orientation, it pixelates :-(

I've got this in the config.xml file at the moment...

```
<gap:splash src="splash/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" width="320" height="480"/>
<gap:splash src="splash/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" width="960" height="640"/>
<gap:splash src="splash/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" width="768" height="1024"/>
<gap:splash src="splash/android/ldpi2.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi"/>
<gap:splash src="splash/android/mdpi2.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi"/>
<gap:splash src="splash/android/hdpi2.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi"/>
```

The images with the 2 on the end are the landscape ones and the ones without are the portrait ones.

I was told to put the width and height values in the portrait ones and then by default, it would take the ones without values as the landscape one. This didn't happen.

Any help is fully appreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: This might help you. <br/>
[Have a look on this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951297/how-to-add-unique-portrait-and-landscape-android-splash-image-to-config-xml-gap

Comment: That only works for the old version of PGB. Newer versions need the gap:qualifier directive.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I finally fixed  for android app with phonegap build [v3.3.0].
Added these lines in config.xml. **Note:** Please give exact name for the image and take care of width and hieght.

```
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />

<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash/screen-ldpi-landscape.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" width="320" height="200"  gap:qualifier="land-ldpi"/>
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash/screen-mdpi-landscape.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" width="480" height="320"  gap:qualifier="land-mdpi"/>
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash/screen-hdpi-landscape.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" width="800" height="480"  gap:qualifier="land-hdpi"/>
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" width="1280" height="720"  gap:qualifier="land-xhdpi"/>
```

Comment: The gap:density is no longer useful, as the gap:qualifier contains it. On the PGB blog it's written, while mentioning gap:qualifier: "All existing attributes are still supported, but consider this the recommended option over the current gap:density attribute."